# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'capfuzz'

Tags: django, python-3.x

When I trying to start the `MobSF` (Mobile-Security Framework) in `Windows 10` by using the command `python manage.py runserver`, I get the following error:

```
c:\Users\username\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF>python manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x000001C247E189D8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 120, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 364, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 351, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 73, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 397, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 36, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 536, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 36, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 529, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "c:\Users\username\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\MobSF\urls.py", line 4, in <module>
    import DynamicAnalyzer.views.android.dynamic
  File "c:\Users\username\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\DynamicAnalyzer\views\android\dynamic.py", line 24, in <module>
    from DynamicAnalyzer.tools.webproxy import (
  File "c:\Users\username\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\DynamicAnalyzer\tools\webproxy.py", line 6, in <module>
    import capfuzz as cp
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'capfuzz'
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Did you install `capfuzz`?

Comment: Did you install the [requirements](https://github.com/MobSF/Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF/blob/master/requirements.txt) for the project?

Comment: Follow the [instructions in the documentation](https://github.com/MobSF/Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF/wiki/1.-Documentation#configuring-static-analyzer) and the `CapFuzz` package will be cloned and configured. The `source venv/bin/activate` line is POSIX-specific, on Windows you'd use `venv\Scripts\activate` instead (note, no `source`, that's the whole command).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.
I tried to install Capfuzz but the error is getting like - 
"C:\Users\sunil_m\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF>pip3 install capfuzz
Collecting capfuzz
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement capfuzz (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for capfuzz"
- Please help me to resolve this issue. Also, I followed the steps as provided in the document.

Answer (score 0):

Install **CapFuzz** via these commands.

```
 git clone https://github.com/MobSF/CapFuzz.git 
 cd CapFuzz
 python setup.py install
```